# Rails Test failed could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

i'm trying to run tests on my ruby on rails application but when i type rails test, it return this error:

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

it seems that it require the gem pg, or a PostgresSQL database, but i'd like to run it in sqlite3 database,so i check my Gemfile and database.yml

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  #database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do 
  gem "pg"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise','~>4.7.1'
```

i've tried to run rails db:migrate and rails db:create the two sqlite database are present in the db direcotry, is there other things that i've miss?
thank's

Comment: Try leaving `gem sqlite3` in the global scope and run `spring stop`, maybe it'll fix it

Comment: thak's for your advice it resolve the problem.... i'm new in ruby on rails, but why i have to leave the sqlite gem in the gem file when i defined that in the same file but in the section test?